# In input type date display date from database in php

Tags: php, html

```php
<label class="w3-text-teal"><b>Date Of Birth</b></label>
<input class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey" type="date" value="<?php echo strftime('%Y-%m-%d',strtotime($row['date_of_birth'])); ?>" name="dob" required>
```

Above is my code and I want to fetch database values of the date of birth in my input type date attribute.
Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: What did you try to fetch date from database?

Comment: `<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['date_of_birth'])); ?>`

Comment: what was the issue ??

Comment: I have a form where the user will input his date of birth using a date attribute of html 5.
To display his date of birth the value will be fetched from database.

Answer (score 0):

Please use yyyy-mm-dd format as a value. you have wrong spelled strftime function it should be strtotime

```
<label class="w3-text-teal"><b>Date Of Birth</b></label> <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-light-grey" type="date" value="<?php echo strtotime('%Y-%m-%d',strtotime($row['date_of_birth'])); ?>" name="dob" required>
```